# SSIS lookup with Update possible?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ssis, activex, dts

I am converting a DTS update lookup to an SSIS lookup with an update query. So far it doesn't seem to work.

**OLD DTS ACTIVE X CODE:**

value = DTSLookups("apple").Execute(DTSSource("ID2"))

**SQL Query in DTS:**

UPDATE TABLE1 SET STAMP="TEST" WHERE (ID = ?)

**In SSIS:**

Create a lookup, use same above query, and I get an error if I click on column: **"Parameter information cannot be derived from SQL statements. Set parameter information before preparing command"**

IS there anyway to accomplish this in SSIS with a lookup? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Please have pity on those of us who never learned DTS, and those of us who have deliberately forgotten DTS: tell us what result you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: No problem. I just want to update Table1 and set stamp to test where ID = ID2. ID2 is used as an argument in the active x code that is represented by the ?. In SSIS, I want to use the same update.

Comment: How is this "lookup" determining the set of ID to be updated?

Comment: In ssis I would click on columns, and drag ID2 to the available columns. Unfortunately since I keep getting the above error I cant click on that tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Old way

To perform updates in SSIS, you will want to look at the [OLE DB transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141138.aspx) as it will allow you to do the update as expected.

### Better way

You however don't want to use OLE DB transformation as it will fire off singleton update statements for every bloody row flowing through a dataflow and your performance will be abysmal. Instead, for all the rows needed updated, use a conditional split and redirect them into a staging table. After the dataflow, wire up an execute SQL task to perform a mass update of all the rows that need to be fixed. Your database will thank you. [Andy Leonard](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/) is a great resource to start with, here's an article he did that describes his [incremental load pattern](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/62063/)

Comment: By staging table do you mean destination? The dataflow has many other steps after that, so I cant end it there.